# apparent discrepancy with sizeof and addressof

Tags: c, sizeof, address-operator

sizeof(long) returns 8 bytes but the &along (address of a long) is 12 hex digits (48-bits) or 6 bytes. On OS X 64-bit compiled with clang. Is there a discrepancy here or is this a genuine 64-bit address space?

Comment: Perhaps I should have used different words or different arrangement of word. I do realize the difference between address operator and sizeof operator. Somehow there was/is a subliminal presumption that if the sizeof a (primitive) type is 8 bytes, its adress should also be 8 bytes long. If the address is not 8 bytes, then it does not appear to be a 64-bit system. That said, almost all of your replies were helpful to understand that, as @Jens Gustedt put it, "...64-bit for addresses but not all of these are used...". Thanks very much to all who responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect modern systems use 64 bit for addresses but not all of these are used by the system since 2 to the 64 is an amount of memory no one will use in a near future. Under linux you can find out what your machine actually uses by doing `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. On my machine I have e.g

> address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

so this would allow for 64 GiB of physical memory and 256 TiB of virtual memory. This is largely enough for what this machine will ever encounter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're conflating two different concepts. Sizeof tells you how long a long is, not now long an address is. A long takes up six bytes of memory, but the pointer to it (apparently) takes only 6 (or more likely, takes 8, but the first two are all-zero because of how the memory is laid out)

Let me expand some explanation about address spaces. While pointers are 8 bytes long in a 64 bit processor, the address space rarely needs that much. That allows 2^64 bytes to be addressed, much more than we need. So, for simplicity, many processors and compilers only use 48 of those bits. See this wikipedia link for a few useful diagrams:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses

Comment: Interesting, the first two bytes being all zero. Could you expand on "how the memory is laid out"?

Answer (score 1):

An address us a memory location.  On a 32-bit system it will be 32-bits long, on a 64-bit system 64-bits, and so on.

The `sizeof` of variable is how much memory it occupies.  They are completely unrelated numbers.

> sizeof(long) returns 8 bytes but the &along (address of a long) is 12 hex digits (48-bits) or 6 bytes.

Yes, because when you print a number the leading 0's aren't printed.  For example:

```
int x = 0x0000000F;
printf( "%X", x );
// prints "F"
```

Comment: Thats the point. It is not "showing" a 64-bit address, only 48-bits (12 hex digits)
A variable of type long occupies 8 bytes.
Here are the addresses of some variables of type long:
The address of a is: 0x7fff6338eb08
The address of b is: 0x7fff6338eb00
The address of c is: 0x7fff6338eaf8

Comment: They are perhaps not completely unrelated. My understanding is that the size of a memory address determines the maximum amount of memory that can be referenced. So if the size of an address above is 48-bit, how is it a 64-bit system?

Comment: @spinozagl: Because the leading 0's aren't printed. `sizeof( some_pointer_type) == 8`, that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact reason why you're seeing this, but current 64-bit processors typically don't actually have a 64-bit address space.  The extra hardware involved would be a waste, since 48 bits of address space is more than I expect to need in my lifetime.  It could be that you're seeing a truncated version of the address (i.e., the address is not being front-padded with zeros).

Comment: It could be, as you say, a truncated version of the address.